# Old time sign board at a race track, what's "h ft"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I’d like to ask about the following sentence from the Silver Blaze by Conan Doyle.

Wessex Plate. 50 sovs each h ft with 1000 sovs added for four and five year olds. Second, £300. Third, £200.

This must be an old style sign board hung up on a horse racing field. 
I don’t know what the first part “50 sovs each h ft 1000 sovs added” means.
So 50 sovs is as an entry fee for the horse-owners who put their horse on the race, right? "h
I don’ know what the heck does it mean at “h ft” part. 
And “1000 sovs added” means the management of the race added 1000 sovs as a prize money, right? Does this mean the first place winner gets 1000 sovs?
Would someone enlighten me?

Comment: @ChrisH - Not in this case. It stands for “half forfeit”

Comment: @Jim that makes more sense. I didn't have time earlier to get further but thought my speculation might help someone else. As it's more likely to confuse, I'll delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a 'sign board'.

> As the drag drew up in the enclosure near the grand stand I glanced at
>   **the card** to see the entries.

Cards listing the day's races were printed and made available to people at the racecourse.

Answered [here](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/horse-race-term.3541162/):

> **Wessex Plate:** The name of the race
>
> **50 sovs each:** The cost to enter a horse (50 sovereigns)
>
> **h ft:** Half forfeit. If a horse is withdrawn,
>   then only 25 sovereigns are returned
>
> **with 1000 sovs added:** The race sponsor has added 1000 sovereigns to the prize fund
>
> **for four and five year olds:** The race is open to horses aged four and five years
>
> **Second, £300:** The prize money is for coming second is £300, fixed (it is not a
>   proportion of the prize fund)
>
> **Third, £200:** The prize money for coming third is £200, fixed (it is not a proportion of the prize fund)
>
> **New course:** The course it is run on (the venue clearly has more than one
>   course)
>
> **(one mile and five furlongs):** The distance run. There are
>   eight furlongs in a mile, and a mile is 1760 yards, 5280 feet or
>   approximately 1609 metres.

A 'sov' (sovereign) was a gold one-pound coin, also an alternative term for a pound (currency).

To be noted:

> Although Conan Doyle was a sporting man, he knew little about
>   horseracing, and mistakes in terminology and racing customs abound.

[Discovering Sherlock Holmes (Stanford University)](http://sherlockholmes.stanford.edu/2007/notes2_1.html)